# Limiting Access to django admin via applications

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-admin

Is it possible to limit what admin pages a user is able to VIEW and modify i know it is currently possible to limit changes to them, but is it possibly to limit a user via permissions or otherwise to only the administration views for one app. If possibly i am also aiming that superusers can access the standard django admin

Looking around in the docs it looks like AdminSite is where i should be headed

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible using django permission system. [Check out](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test). You can easily extends this to your own views.

All you have to do is create a group in django admin, remove/give it permission for only those you want to allow. And then assign the desired user to this group.

Remember, permission also limits 'add/change/delete' separately. But works only to limit permissions on type of objects as a whole and not on particular objects.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Good answer, but your link is a bit confusing, it goes to the wrong anchor in the page.

Comment: Thanks hora. i fixed the link.